# Why can't I mimic page in jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript

I am viewing the source of http://raphaeljs.com/growing-pie.html . And copying all the relevant stuff into [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/9eFGq/). But the page is not working at all. I don't get any errors in the fiddle either, except this odd warning: Detected baseUrl as https://towtruck.mozillalabs.com . Anyway, i cant find any differences between the two pages and cant figure out why the fiddle isn't working. Thanks for your help!!! `<:)>`

Comment: Per the console: ***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js*** Doesn't look like they like you trying to access the file from outside their domain...

Comment: yeah, they are not providing a cdn, so you should host that stuff yourself.

Comment: you should access raphael.js from a cdn

Comment: I dont get that error in chrome, and now i have updated the link to raphael...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/watson/9eFGq/6/

Comment: @Watson See version 3 of your fiddle or check my answer. Selecting it isn't enough, because you are overwriting the window.onload event handler. Remove your code from window.onload as well as JSFiddle already puts your code in it: jsfiddle.net/9eFGq/3

Comment: @Watson I still get it on your page. Load the fiddle and then press "Run". It appears on the console...

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you need to include the Raphael library. Just selected it in the sidebar and pulled your code out of the onload handler in the JSFiddle in my comment.

Comment: oh, it was the onload handler that messed it up, thanks a bunch!!